# SSRS report export to Excel: need a column in "Number" format

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I'm using SSRS 2005 and I have a financial report. I would like a column to be in number format when exported to Excel.

How can I specify a column to be exported in number format?

Comment: if i set the format property to "=Format(Fields!AppraiseePsNo.Value,"N") ".. the no's are replcaed by "N" string in excel... can any one suggest me

Comment: Make sure that N is in English, not in another language

Comment: i have set the property as N.. but still my excel sheet column is showing "general"

Comment: But the number formating in excel is correct right? Try also #,##0.00 as format string instead of N

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your 
`<MarkupType>None</MarkupType>` not `<MarkupType>HTML</MarkupType>`for the textbox in your tablix or Table.

Then change the Expression of the textbox to   `=CInt(Format(Fields.DumpValue.Value, "#,###.0"))`

Hope it helps

Comment: I have spend almost 10 working days and try many method like convert dataset data type by SQL query, multiply 1.00 etc, but not work, But this solved my problem!! I don't know why <MarkupType> will change to "HTML" and not noticable and editable on Visual Studio property window. THANK YOU very much!

Answer (score 0):

For every textbox in the column that contains numeric values, select it and set the **Format property** to **N** (number)

Comment: ya i have set that . whether it is correct??   =Format(Fields!AppraiseePsNo.Value,"N")

Comment: Set the field value to Fields!AppraiseePsNo.Value. Use format directly to the textbox.